# React: Creating Another instance of the same control

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created an app which is working pretty well. My app.jsx looks like

```
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <DimensionPicker dimensionName="genre"/>
        <TableControl />
    </div>
)

export default App;
```

Well. this is good. but now I want another instance of dimension picker on the same report like

```
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <DimensionPicker dimensionName="genre"/>
        <DimensionPicker dimensionName="year"/>
        <TableControl />
    </div>
)

export default App;
```

Well it turns out that this is pretty hard to do because the second instance will overwrite the state which I have created in my store.

How can this situation be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem here is that both Instances have the same business logic, as everything is handled internally. So both override the same state in your store, cause both Instances trigger the same callbacks.

What I do, when I want one Presentational Component to have different functionality is simply wrap them and inject the required callbacks as props.

I would do it like this (pseudo code):

```
GenrePicker extends Component {
    handleBehaviour() {
      // define GenrePicker specific logic here
      dispatch(STATE_CHANGE_GENREPICKER)
    }        

    render() {
     return (<DimensionPicker onPickHandler={this.handleBehaviour} dimensionName="genre"/>)
    }
}

YearPicker extends Component {
   handleBehaviour() {
      // define YearPicker specific logic here
      dispatch(STATE_CHANGE_YEARPICKER)
   }        

   render() {
      return (<DimensionPicker onPickHandler={this.handleBehaviour} dimensionName="year"/>)
   }
}
```

And in your App

```
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <GenrePicker />
        <YearPicker />
        <TableControl />
    </div>
)

export default App;
```

I always use to program my presentational components only against props. In your case I would treat the DimensionPicker as a dumb presentational Component and use concrete Components to inject the required logic.

Regarding the problem with the state override. Shouldn't both Components have their own state property?  state = { selectedYear: '', selectedGenre: '' } and therefore dispatch an action in their's handleBehaviour() method that only propagates it's own state change?